# AG Grid: How to automatically fit to max inside a resizable div?

Tags: ag-grid, autofill

I have an ag grid that correctly shows within a div container and fills it. This is simply done by calling ...gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit() on the 'firstDataRenedered' output binding event which fires ONCE when the data is available and bound by grid's [rowData] input binding. Cool.

I am also able to resize the div container the grid is in. However, as the div is resized the grid does not automatically fill with it (note there is no new data so the 'firstDataRenedered' output binding event doesn't fire). How can I automatically resize the grid to fill the dynamic div?

Answer (score 2):

the best solution i got in my mind is to use the `gridSizeChanged` event and invoke `gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit()`

here's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/make-ag-grid-columns-100-of-width-when-grid-is-resized?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for you